# Form not submitting in Jquery after user corrects errors (return false;)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've ran into a pickle. I am writing a simple mortgage calculator that sends data to calc.php through ajax.

Using jquery, I am checking to make sure that the user enters the appropriate values in the requested fields; both purchase price and down payment should be numbers (working), down payment can't be greater than purchase price (working), when a term is selected, interest rate auto populates (working) and an error message appears if either term or interest rate aren't populated (working).

When user submits the form and any of the mandatory items are missing, error messages display advising... however, the form doesn't submit when errors are corrected by the user.

As you will soon see by looking at my not-too-sophisticated code, I am still learning Jquery and will appreciate any input you can give me.

Thanks in advance for the help.

HTML form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Mortgage</h1>
    <form action="calc.php" method="post" id="mortgage-form">
        <p class="errorMessage" id="shouldBeNumber">*This value can only contain numbers</p>
        <p id="pPrice"><span class="errorMessage" id="PPmustBeNumber">*</span>Purchase Price: 
            <input type="text" name="purchase-price" id="purchase-price" value="0"/>
            <span class="errorMessage" id="purchasePriceError">Please enter a number value!</span>
        </p>
        <p id="dPayment"><span class="errorMessage" id="DPmustBeNumber">*</span>Down Payment: 
            <input type="text" name="down-payment" id="down-payment" value="0"/>
            <span class="errorMessage" id="downPaymentError">Down payment value must be less than Purchase Price!</span>
        </p>
        <p id="term">
            <select id="loan-term">
                <option value="noValueSelected">-- Select a Term -- </option>
                <option value="15yrs">15 Years</option>
                <option value="20yrs">20 Years</option>
                <option value="30yrs">30 Years</option>
            </select><span class="errorMessage" id="termRequired"> * Term is required.</span>
        </p>
        <div id="interest-rate"></div>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Calculate!" /></p>
    </form>

        <footer>
            <p>
                &copy; Copyright  by Ricardo
            </p>
        </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my JQUERY

```
    $(function() {
//HIDE errors
$('.errorMessage').hide();

//Do something when loan-term changes
$('#loan-term').change(function(){
    var loanTerm = $(this).val();
    var interestOption = '';
    //alert(loanTerm);
    if (loanTerm == '15yrs') {
        interestOption += "<option value='15yrFixed'>15 Year Fixed: 2.88%    </option>";
    } else if (loanTerm == '20yrs') {
        interestOption += "<option value='20yrFixed'>20 Year Fixed: 3.52%</option>";
    } else if (loanTerm == '30yrs') {
        interestOption += "<option value='30yrFixed'>30 Year Fixed: 4.2%</option>";
    }

    if (loanTerm != "noValueSelected") {
        var interestRate = 
        "<select id='interest-rate'><option value='selectInterestRate'>-- Select an Interest Rate -- </option>" + interestOption + "</select><span class='errorMessage' id='interestRequired'> * This field is required.</span>";
        $('#interest-rate').html(interestRate).show();
    } else if (loanTerm == "noValueSelected") {
        $('#interest-rate').hide();
    }
});//END loan-term check

$('#mortgage-form').submit(function() {

    var purchasePrice = $('#purchase-price').val();
    var downPayment = $('#down-payment').val();
    var loanTerm = $('#loan-term').val();
    var interestRate = $('#interest-rate').val();

    function containsNumber(val) {
        return /^(\d|,)+$/.test(val)
    }

    if (containsNumber(purchasePrice) == true && containsNumber(downPayment) == true ) {
        $('#PPmustBeNumber').hide();
        $('#DPmustBeNumber').hide();
        $('#shouldBeNumber').hide();
        //alert(purchasePrice + downPayment);
        //CHECK IF DOWNPAYMENT IS LESS THAN PURCHASE PRICE. 
        if (downPayment <  purchasePrice) {
            $('#downPaymentError').hide();
        } else {
            $('#downPaymentError').show();
        }
    } else if (containsNumber(purchasePrice) == false){ 
        $('#PPmustBeNumber').show();
        $('#shouldBeNumber').show();
    } else if (containsNumber(downPayment) == false) {
        $('#DPmustBeNumber').show();
        $('#shouldBeNumber').show();
    }
    if (loanTerm != "noValueSelected") {
        $('#termRequired').hide();
            $("#interest-rate").change(function() {
                if (interestRate != "selectInterestRate"){
                    $('#interestRequired').hide();
                } else if (interestRate == "selectInterestRate"){
                    $('#interestRequired').show();
                }   
            })
    } else if (loanTerm == "noValueSelected"){
            $('#termRequired').show();
    } 


if ( purchasePrice && downPayment && loanTerm && interestRate) {
var data = new Object();
    data.purchasePrice = purchasePrice;
    data.downPayment = downPayment;
    data.loanTerm = loanTerm;
    data.interestRate = interestRate;
    data.interestOption = interestOption;

    //create an object of Ajax options:
    var options = new Object();

    //Establish each setting:

    options.data = data;
    options.dataType= 'text';
    options.type = 'get';
    options.url = 'calc.php';

    //perform the request:
    $.ajax(options);    
}

    return false;

}); //END SUBMIT FUNCTION
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery's ajax functions, you don't need to submit the form. Also, if you want the form to submit, you need to put in an IF function to return true, or it won't submit. Your code simply returns false no matter what. You need to make it conditional, so if the errors are not displayed because the criteria is met by the user, THEN the form returns true and sends, yet you wouldn't need the ajax then, as I have mentioned.

Sample code to validate with jQuery and submit the form normally:
For this to work, I would change the submit button from type="submit" to type="button" which will prevent it from submitting automatically.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    // put all your code to check inputs for errors here.
    $('#mortgage-form').submit();
});
```

This way you can use javascript for the validation and then send the form to the calc.php page  just how you need it to work.

Comment: Then I am wondering if I did something wrong; after submitting the form, i'm supposed to see calc.php, where I've displayed a number of options to perform the calculations and display the calculated values. Any ideas what I might have missed?   Thanks for the prompt response, btw. I trully appreciate it.

Comment: If you want the form to submit normally and display calc.php, then you don't need to send the info using ajax. Basically ajax is a way to "cheat" and send the info WITHOUT refreshing the page or moving to another page. What you may want to do is use jQuery to validate all the inputs and then submit the form normally to get your desired result.

So an example of this would be:
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
    // check all your inputs here for errors.
});

Answer (score 0):

I would just let the form submit as normal without doing the ajax. The primary issue I see is that you don't have a way for the form to `return true;` which allows the form to actually submit. Try subbing out your submit function for this below and that should get the ball rolling for you.

```
$('#mortgage-form').submit(function () {

var purchasePrice = $('#purchase-price').val();
var downPayment = $('#down-payment').val();
var loanTerm = $('#loan-term').val();
var interestRate = $('#interest-rate').val();

function containsNumber(val) {
    return /^(\d|,)+$/.test(val)
}

if (containsNumber(purchasePrice) == true && containsNumber(downPayment) == true) {
    $('#PPmustBeNumber').hide();
    $('#DPmustBeNumber').hide();
    $('#shouldBeNumber').hide();
    //alert(purchasePrice + downPayment);
    //CHECK IF DOWNPAYMENT IS LESS THAN PURCHASE PRICE. 
    if (downPayment < purchasePrice) {
        $('#downPaymentError').hide();
    } else {
        $('#downPaymentError').show();
    }
} else if (containsNumber(purchasePrice) == false) {
    $('#PPmustBeNumber').show();
    $('#shouldBeNumber').show();
} else if (containsNumber(downPayment) == false) {
    $('#DPmustBeNumber').show();
    $('#shouldBeNumber').show();
}
if (loanTerm != "noValueSelected") {
    $('#termRequired').hide();
    $("#interest-rate").change(function () {
        if (interestRate != "selectInterestRate") {
            $('#interestRequired').hide();
        } else if (interestRate == "selectInterestRate") {
            $('#interestRequired').show();
        }
    })
} else if (loanTerm == "noValueSelected") {
    $('#termRequired').show();
}


if (purchasePrice && downPayment && loanTerm && interestRate) {
    var data = new Object();
    data.purchasePrice = purchasePrice;
    data.downPayment = downPayment;
    data.loanTerm = loanTerm;
    data.interestRate = interestRate;
    data.interestOption = interestOption;

    //create an object of Ajax options:
    var options = new Object();

    //Establish each setting:

    options.data = data;
    options.dataType = 'text';
    options.type = 'get';
    options.url = 'calc.php';

    return true;
}

return false;

}); //END SUBMIT FUNCTION
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So instead of using AJAX, I changed my code to simple JQUERY validation and then normal form submission (which is what I wanted). I changed the form from GET to POST. I am still using JQUERY to validate the form, and then just send the values once everything is OK.

PHP will then handle the equations.

Thank you to everyone's suggestion; you inspired me to solve my issue.

Cheers!